# How to arrange divs like this

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange divs like on the picture, but I dont know how.

Maybe the padding could set auto?

[image: category listed]

can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer unless you specify how this needs to behave if the viewport is resized.

Comment: Yar, i know i need to use float, but i want to set the padding dynamic/auto. I need the divs to have the same margin. in this case it is 20 px.

Comment: If you haven't used bootstrap, try it. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: By the looks of your layout, there's nothing dynamic about the margins or padding - those look consistent on all the boxes.

Comment: "... like this" is a bad title for a question. Put more details on it, think about how useful it will be for people who will read it afterwards.

Comment: i don't know how to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach that might help [w3c FlexBox model spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)... but hard to say without more details about your scenario.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this please explain why?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing this with inline-block. Probably the best method for this type of thing, but not universally supported in lower versions of IE.

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NdK7c/

FYI: You can create spacing between each of the elements by adding positive `letter-spacing` to the parent UL element, and then adding `letter-spacing: normal` on the child li elements to rectify the inherited letter spacing.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2suGg/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
           .main-container{
               width:400px; 
               background: #007caa;
               display: block
           }
            .block{ 
                display: block; 
                display: inline-block;
                width:auto;
                margin:5px; 
                background: #dbf2fa;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            *+html .block{
                display: inline
            }
        </style>
        
      </head>
      
      <body>
          <div class="main-container">
              <div class="block">Development</div>
              <div class="block">Designing</div>
              <div class="block">Drupal</div>
              <div class="block">Omega</div>
              <div class="block">Drupal</div>
              <div class="block">Designing</div>
              <div class="block">Development</div>
              <div class="block">Drupal</div>
              <div class="block">Omega</div>
              <div class="block">Development</div>
              <div class="block">Drupal</div>
              <div class="block">Omega</div>
    
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can arrange the div's like you mentioned image by using CSS 'display' and 'float' styles.
If using float style means we have to clear the float at the end of the last float div.

please refer the link http://jsfiddle.net/ybhR9/2/ for style "display" concept.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to achieve a justified alignment (aligned at both the left side and the right side).

I suggest to assign the margins from Javascript, then let the divs flow inline. No need to float.

Algorithm:

```
- Whenever the container is resized
-- Create a copy of the container such that it is not user-visible but still layouted by the browser
-- Set all element margins to zero
-- Collect the elements by rows
-- For each row (except the last one, maybe)
--- Calculate the largest element margin that will not cause an overflow
--- Round down to whole pixels
--- Determine the deficit due to rounding
--- Set each element the margin, and distribute the deficit (one pixel to each)
-- Force the browser to recalculate the layout
-- Replace the container with the new one
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something better and work from there:

```
ul{
  text-align:justify;
}
ul li{
  display:inline;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  line-height:60px;
  background-color:orange;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my answer. Maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This works in IE but not in Chrome.. :(

```
.enlarge-categores  ul{
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify:distribute;


}
.enlarge-categores ul li{
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px; 
    display:inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:#f39900;

}
```